# Child Node's attribute value using DOM

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I want to get the attribute value of a childnode in a xml file using DOM parser without XPath..Is there any way that I can do that

I have my node structure like this:

```
<parent type = "xxxxx">
    <child type = "yyyy">
       <grandchild name = "xxxxx" type ="zzzz" />
       <grandchild name = "xxxyx" type ="zzzx" />
      </child>
```

I want the names of the grand child given the child's type as input

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901744/parsing-xml-file-with-dom-java?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is this child node directly under the parent or at a lower level?
- Is there more than one child node?

One could use something like this:

```
NodeList childNodes = parent.getChildNodes();

for(int i = 0; i < childNodes.size(); i++) {
   System.out.println(childNodes.item(i)
                                .getAttributes()
                                .getNamedItem("myAttribute")
                                .getNodeValue());
}
```

This is one way that I have done it.

Comment: Hi,I have posted my structure above..Can u look into that please??

Comment: Hi,Using your method I am able to retrieve all the grandchild attribute values..How can I query it to get only those attribute values taking a particular parent type as input..

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1. First, check whether the node is an `Element`. If so, cast to it.
2. Call [`Element.getAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29).